# Lists for built-in functions that can work without brackets

Tags: functions, undocumented, language-design

I just noticed that `Exit` and `Quit` can work without brackets i.e. a single

```
Exit
```

or

```
Quit
```

will quit the kernel. Quite surprising!

This isn't mentioned in the document of them. Is there a list for functions with this feature?

Well, I admit I asked this question mainly to show the discovery above :D

Comment: `Pi` and `E` and `EulerGamma` though you could argue these are constants (and boringly return themselves). I'd look for functions that take no arguments, though I can't imagine there are many interesting ones that aren't constants.

Comment: These have been mentioned before and they came as quite a surprise to me.  Following standard syntax these should be `Exit[]` or `Quit[]`.  I suspect that these were included only to reduce the frustration of new users who were entering `Exit` and not getting the desired effect.  I have never looked for additional cases though they may exist.

Comment: They work without brackets when it's the only input to the cell, not when they are part of any expression though. Suggesting this is some sort of ancient flow control loophole, I dunno.

Comment: I suppose `Nothing` will not fit your criterion? Tho `Nothing` and `Nothing[]` are equivalent, it is handy to be able to do things like `Nothing @@ {{1}, {2}}` and `Nothing @@@ {{1}, {2}}`.

Comment: @J.M.isaway It fits, please add this as an answer :) . (BTW why do you think it doesn't fit my criterion? )

Comment: I got confused by the answer you downvoted, but after some thinking, it is indeed an admissible example; I've put it in now.

Answer (score 6):

At the OP's request, I am adding the following:

`Nothing` is a function with very peculiar behavior:

```
Nothing === Nothing[] === Nothing[x, y]
   True
```

This means that

```
Nothing & /@ {{a}, {b}}
```

and

```
Nothing /@ {{a}, {b}}
```

and

```
Nothing @@@ {{a}, {b}}
```

all give `{}` as the result.

Answer (score 5):

Just noticed `Return` can work without brackets when it's inside a dialog:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
Here
```

Could also work without brackets.

Comment: (-1) I'm sorry, but `Here` is not a function.

Comment: @xzczd what is the definition of a function here? p.s. how about `Now`?

Comment: @Kuba Perhaps I should say "function relationship" or "Head"? `Now` is not, either. Both `Here` and `Now` are used without `[]`, they're built-in symbols, but not functions.

Comment: Right, fair enough.

Comment: @xzczd  Yes, you are right.